# Print values without new line

Tags: fortran, fortran90

How to print many values without line breaks?

```
PRINT *, "foo:", foo, ", bar:", bar, ", baz:", baz
```

Apparently, this is possible with `WRITE` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661975/supressing-line-breaks-in-fortran-95-write-statements) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714322/fortran-write-without-newline)). How to achieve the same with `PRINT` and its different syntax while printing several values?

Comment: Are you asking how to specify an explicit format when using `print`?

Comment: Print is basically a less-customizable version of write. Why are you attempting to do this?

Comment: Just use write, print is just for simple stuff.

Comment: Is `print` just a shorthand for `write`, even with Fortran90? Yet, `write(*,*,advance='no') "foo:", foo, ", bar:", bar, ", baz:", baz` doesn't work for me. It says: `error #6568: This use of the ADVANCE, SIZE, or EOR specifier is invalid.` I don't think that it's the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377521/non-advancing-read-in-fortran-with-free-format), which tries to read.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `write` statement provides an optional `advance` specifier, but `print` does not.

Multiple `write` statements with `advance="no"` can be made at different places in your code in order to print multiple items to the same line. Just as an example, using it from within a `do` loop:

```
do i=1,3
    write(*, fmt="(1x,a,i0)", advance="no") "loop #", i
end do
write(*,*) ! Assumes default "advance='yes'".
write(*,*) "--OK, the loop is done!"
```

```
! Example output:
 loop #1 loop #2 loop #3
 --OK, the loop is done!
```

Note that `advance` can't be used with list-directed output (using the "*" to "print anything"). Therefore, I've shown an example format specifier `fmt="(1x,a,i0)"` which will print a single blank space, a character string, and a single integer for each write statement. A language reference and/or your compiler documentation comes in handy. See, [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678687#0C08E26A-2C90-4EE6-82E6-040AD0ED56F3), for example.

As others have suggested, if this is the desired behavior, it's best to use `write`. If for some reason you still prefer to use `print`, then you should probably assemble your output items into a single variable or list of variables before printing it.

Comment: The following can be useful to learn more about the format descriptor: http://www.chem.ox.ac.uk/fortran/format.html, although I haven't found anything to display matrices without loops like `PRINT` offers.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you show an example of what `print` can do that `write` does not, possibly in your original post?

Comment: @MattP I have a lot of variables that I am trying to print one line and they have to separated by commas, to create a .csv file. Is there a more practical solution than a loop?

Comment: @HermanToothrot That might be a good new question. Everything on one line, with comma separation? Sure, absolutely. I recommend you look into implied do-loops, and the 'unlimited repeat' format specifier. (The same ideas can be used even for multiple lines, if you feel like you really need a one-liner, but the syntax looks a little tricky unless you're used to it. )